# Analyzing Proximity Pattern Data in Gorillas

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test, chi-squared-test, spearman-rho

I have a whole bunch of data about proximity patterns between 2 gorillas (distance in meters, taken during set time intervals). I'm interested in comparing the differences in proximity between the 2 individuals in two enclosures.

So I have data from Enclosure A, and Enclosure B. Now, initially I just ran a simple T-test to determine the basic variation between the 2 data sets, (p<0.01). So I know there is a significant difference.

However, I want to group the distances into categories, and use the count from each category to determine the difference - E.g. <1 m is observed 100 times, 1-2 m is observed 200 times, etc.

I also want to compare proximity vs. feeding. So, distance between the two gorillas and whether or not one of them is feeding. Initially I thought of using Spearman's correlation, but I don't have 2 sets of continuous variables. Distance is continuous but feeding is categorical (yes/no).

In both instances I don't know which tests to use. Any help?

Comment: What's the main reason for splitting into categories? Are you just trying to compare the distributions of dstances (in which case I'd say 'don't split')? In the second one, if the aim is to compare whether feeding affects distance you might look at some form of linear model (possibly regression/ANOVA, possibly something like a gamma GLM) with feeding as a dummy predictor, along with enclosure; you might want to consider an interaction term in the model.

Comment: The idea is that ranges are more indicative of actual behaviour. It's more informative to know what proportion of the obtained scans they spent far away from each other, and how this differs based on enclosure, rather than just the means, which give a pretty simplistic analysis of their behaviour.

Comment: I fully understand the desire to get more information than the mean -- the entire distribution would be of interest -- but that doesn't explain why you would split the data into categories.